# Google cloud speech to text - How to get numbers in digit

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I'm using the google cloud speech to text api, it's working great!

As for the response, I'd need to get numbers in digits (1,2,3) instead of text (one, two, three).

I notice that if the number is placed inside the sentence, it's in text format.

Is there a parameter for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context of your input, you can definitely convert numbers in text format to actual numbers. You can include `speechContexts` on your config. A class token can be assigned to the `phrases` field. To better explain this here is an example taken from the [speech context documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation#class_tokens).

> For example, to improve the transcription of address numbers from your
> source audio, provide the value $ADDRESSNUM in your SpeechContext
> object.

The config with speechContexts will look like this.

```
  "config": {
    "encoding":"LINEAR16",
    "sampleRateHertz": 8000,
    "languageCode":"en-US",
    "speechContexts": [{
      "phrases": ["$ADDRESSNUM"]
     }]
  }
```

The `$ADDRESSNUM` is an example of a class token. What it does is when the context of the speech is about addresses, it converts the digits in words to actual digits.

[image]

There are a lot of other class tokens that are available. You can further look into the class tokens in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/class-tokens).

Comment: and how can we send the config to google api server? when I read the code, I see `HTTP POST` request which attributes are in query string (language,api-key and ...) and request body contains Audio Data. I'm looking for a working sample but did not find any